# How to use Mockito to verify a function was called either 3 or 6 times?

Tags: mockito, integration-testing

In mockito, I can do something like this to verify my function was called exactly 3 times

```
verify(mock, times(3)).someMethod("was called three times");
```

But sometimes, it can be called 6 times, causing the test to fail. (This is because the test relies on an at-least-once-delivery queue, and the function will be called 6 times when the queue delivers a second time).

How can I assert `someMethod` is called 3 times OR 6 times, but fail if it is called say 4 times?

Comment: Hi, did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try this kind of behaviour :

```
try {
    Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.times(3)).someMethod(argumentMatcher);
}
catch(TooManyActualInvocations e) {
    Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.times(6)).someMethod(argumentMatcher);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to say that, but chances are that this kind of approach shows a design problem.